# SOCIAL TABLES 504 response when add guest to guest_list

Tags: social-tables

I follow tutorial 
Please tell, why when i try send post request i receive 504 error ?
But if i send from from api console https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console it`s work fine

I send request from python 
headers :
'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer valid token'

guest list is valid 
token is valid
get requests work fine

POST /4.0/guestlists/{guestlist_id}/guests

python 3.7.2 with lib requests==2.21.0 urllib3==1.24.1

```py
r = requests.post('https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/guestlists/965d8450-daf3- 
11e9-9e6a-1fbad5325279/guests', data=json.dumps({ 
"id":"1231231231","first_name":"fname","last_name":"lname","email":"aa@aaa.aa" 
})) 
r.status_code # 504 
r.text # ''
r.method # post
r.url 
'https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/guestlists/965d8450-daf3-11e9-9e6a-1fbad5325279/guests'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it`s works without json.dumps(dict())
working example:

```
r = requests.post('https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/guestlists/965d8450-daf3- 
11e9-9e6a-1fbad5325279/guests', data={ 
"id":"1231231231","first_name":"fname","last_name":"lname","email":"aa@aaa.aa" 
})
```